# `DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS_FAST` vs `DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS`?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

In Unreal Engine C++, what's the difference between `DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS_FAST` and `DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS` ?

Here is the definition of `DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS_FAST`:

```
#define DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS_FAST(c,v,params) \
{ \
    static const bool bIsValid_##c_##v = ValidateReplicatedClassInheritance(StaticClass(), c::StaticClass(), TEXT(#v)); \
    const TCHAR* DoRepPropertyName_##c_##v(TEXT(#v)); \
    const NetworkingPrivate::FRepPropertyDescriptor PropertyDescriptor_##c_##v(DoRepPropertyName_##c_##v, (int32)c::ENetFields_Private::v, 1); \
    RegisterReplicatedLifetimeProperty(PropertyDescriptor_##c_##v, OutLifetimeProps, params); \
}
```

and here is the definition of `DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS`:

```
#define DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS(c,v,params) \
{ \
    FProperty* ReplicatedProperty = GetReplicatedProperty(StaticClass(), c::StaticClass(),GET_MEMBER_NAME_CHECKED(c,v)); \
    RegisterReplicatedLifetimeProperty(ReplicatedProperty, OutLifetimeProps, params); \
}
```

Whats fast about the fast version?  Why would I ever use the nonfast version?

Answer (score 1):

in the chain call of the DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS_FAST I can’t see property validation for the replication flag (CPF_Net).

I think that you can choose DOREPLIFETIME_WITH_PARAMS_FAST when you absolutely know that your property is marked as Replicated. and to avoid relative function calls.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  (I would of called it `_UNCHECKED` or `_UNSAFE` instead of `_FAST` to make this clearer.)  Do you know what happens if you use the fast version with a property that is not marked Replicated ?

Comment: until both versions (fast and nonfast) don't compile without Replicated or ReplicatedUsing - you can use only fast version :)